# How to use sed on Linux to get values from file name?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

How can I retrieve every portion separately from the following file name?

```
DSA4020_frontcover_20346501_2011-05.doc
```

I want to retrieve the information as below:

```
name = DSA4020
type = frontcover
id =  20346501
date = 2011-05
```

Is it possible to do this with sed?

Comment: Why use sed when you can use cut (or awk) ?

Comment: doesn't matter whether cut or awk. I just need those values. please help me out. thanks!

Comment: See your post in [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140019/how-to-use-sed-on-linux-to-get-values-from-file-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this '`sed`' recipe.

```
echo "DSA4020_frontcover_20346501_2011-05.doc"  \
 | sed 's|\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)_\([^\.]*\).*|name=\1,type=\2,id=\3,date=\4|'
```

gives this nice CSV form,

```
name=DSA4020,type=frontcover,id=20346501,date=2011-05
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to split at every _ after removing the extension:

```
$ echo "DSA4020_frontcover_20346501_2011-05.doc" | cut -d. -f-1 | cut -d_ -f1
DSA4020
```

Replace the very last digit by 2, 3, 4 to get the individual value each time.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of fields is constant :

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do  
    VARS[${i}]=$(echo ${yourfilename} | cut -d _ -f${i})
done
```

Then access ${VARS[i]}...

Alternative :

```
VARS[${i}]=$(echo ${yourfilename} | awk -v i=${i} -F_ '{print $i}'
```

And if supported (bash 3+)

```
for i in {1..5}; do (...)
```

---

If you have multiple filenames, just add a `for` loop to skim through all of them.

Comment: It's only four fields.

Comment: My test routine was five fields long :P I hope OP's clever enough to understand and correct if needed.

Comment: I just noticed, this doesn't remove the file extension either, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Split the filename and store in positional parameters:

```
set -- $(sed 's/_/ /g' <<< ${filename%.doc})
name=$1
type=$2
id=$3
date=$4
```

Comment: Doesn't cut the file extension.

Comment: @Daniel, this part will remove a ".doc" extension: `${filename%.doc}`

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "DSA4020_frontcover_20346501_2011-05.doc" | awk -F '_' '{print " name =" $1 "\n type =" $2 "\n id =" $3 "\n date =" $4 } '
```

output will be like this:

```
name = DSA4020
type = frontcover
id = 20346501
date = 2011-05
```